# Unable to save new record to the sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapps

I am creating a leave system for my company through Sharepoint. I tried customizing the edit form using powerapps. So when I fill all the records in edit form as shown in powerapp.png, and click on save button as in normal sharepoint form, my fields get reset to their defaults and i get 'entry required or invalid value'(see the attachment named 'powerapp.png') and the item isn't added to my sharepoint list.

However the record does get added to list if using normal sharepoint form as shown in normal_sharepoint.png.

Note: I have created a custom text field in powerapp.png which calculates me the leave days excluding weekdays and weekends. ( this is a major requirement)

Also I have enabled content-approval in my sharepoint list because the item is sent to manager for approval. Hence a content-type data field equal to 'Item' always shows up when I open the edit form in normal sharepoint and some unique id is autogenerated. However I enabled the content type field in powerapps too but still the same error.

**powerapp.png**

[image: powerapp.png]

**normal_sharepoint.png**
[image: normal_sharepoint.png]

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure you have filled out all the fields as those asterisked are Required fields. 
Also on the datacard of each of the fields on powerapps, you can change the required property to false if any of the fields is not cumpolsory

Comment: I have actually filled out all fields marked mandatory. I still get the error. My form also has content approval enabled. Can this be a possible source of error? Do you know how to debug this?